# Python: nested for loops for 2d-arrays

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am fairly new to python and have problems with nested for-loops.
I have a file that contains data (number of lines=len(status)) for 1000 different objects (called obj), e.g. date, obj, status and how. I want to create a 2d-array where each column refers to a given obj, and each line gives me the date at which status and how fulfill an if-condition.
I tried the following without success:

```
cols=196
rows=70
databb=np.zeros((rows,cols))
for l in range(len(status)):
    for i in range(col):
        for j in range(rows):
            if (status[l]=='C' and obj[l]==201+i and how[l]=='epoch' ):
                databb[j,i]=date[l]
print(databb[:,0])
```

The print command should give me all dates for my first obj, when the if-statement is fulfilled. And I know that there are at least 70 dates for which it is. But the print command gives me 70 times the same date.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the print statement inside of the loop. After the if statement so that you see the most updated version of each element in `databb` without having to loop over it twice.

```
cols=196
rows=70
databb=np.zeros((rows,cols))
for l in range(len(status)):
    for i in range(col):
        for j in range(rows):
            if (status[l]=='C' and obj[l]==201+i and how[l]=='epoch' ):
                databb[j,i]=date[l]

            print(databb[:,0])
```